# Deploying Visual Studio 2010 Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

is it possible to deploy Visual studio 2010 add-in to vs gallery ? and if not how to make a setup package for it any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front page of the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) includes links "Upload" and "See My Gallery".

So trivially: you can.

Also linked is ["Feedback"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/visualstudio,vsarch,vsdbg,vstest,vstfs,vsdata,vsappdev,visualbasic,visualcsharp,visualc) to an MSDN forum on the subject of the gallery.